How exactly do I use and navigate nvim cmp?
I went through all the steps to setup Markdown Oxide and can get Wikilink Completions to Files and Headings to show up when I type [[ in a markdown file, which use nvim cmp. However I am having trouble actually selecting anything, when I press up down or enter, the selection menu goes away, and when I hit tab, dots .. are inserted.
I looked at the repo readme and the wiki and didn't find instructions for how to use it.

I got it by looking by adding the cmp.setup() function into my init.lua file and adding the mapping helper functions specified in the documentation into cmp.mapping.preset.insert() like so:
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
    ['<Up>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(),
    ['<Down>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(),
    ['<C-b>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
    ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
    ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
    ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }), -- Accept currently selected item. Set `select` to `false` to only confirm explicitly selected items.
  })

